# There are similar tools like FindBugs?

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm searching for similar tools like FindBugs to analyze my code. I only saw that in the links page of the FindBugs site.

I can search in webfor the tools, but I don't know what is the category of this type of program.

I don't searching for the best, but all that can help me to test my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716203/automatic-code-quality-and-architecture-quality-static-code-analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [*A Comparison of Bug Finding Tools for Java*](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/publications.html), which is referenced from the FindBugs site.

Comment: I have to admire the authors' critical examination of their own work.

Answer (score 4):

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) is a great complement to FindBugs.  Wherease FindBugs works on bytecode, PMD analyzes Java source.  Both have their strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should search for the term "[static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)"

You might also like:

- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
- [testability explorer](http://code.google.com/p/testability-explorer/)
- [crap4j](http://www.crap4j.org/)

Answer (score 0):

We utilise [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), which combines many different tools into one package. It's FOSS, web enabled, provides problem drill down support, historical comparison, nicely integrates with maven.

Comment: @Renato Dinhani Conceição If you're using maven then it is very simple -- configure Sonar as part of .m2/setting.xml and then run mvn sonar:sonar on your maven-enabled project. Sonar uses Derby be default as its database to store project specific data. It can be configured to use any other RDBMS such as MySQL, Oracle etc. Pls consult Sonar documentation (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Install+Sonar) for more details.